# RxSwift ordering by date after convertiing from string

Tags: date, mapping, rx-swift

I have and array I'm subscribing, objects in this array has a property date, in form of a String. I need to order the array I receive from subscription by such date, but cannot make it if it is a string, I think need to convert that string in a date then use it to order them. I know how to convert from string to date, but no idea where to do

object is like to

```
struct Task: codable {
var date = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
}

self.viewModel.tasks
    .map({ items in
       return items.sorted(by: { $0.date.compare($1.date) == .orderedAscending })
     })
            .bind(to: self.tasksTableView.rx.items(dataSource: self.dataSource))
            .disposed(by: self.rx.disposeBag)
```

Comment: Need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to change the type of `date` then do it all inside your `map`'s closure.

```
tasks.map { tasks in
    tasks.sorted(by: { lhs, rhs in
        dateFormatter.date(from: lhs.date)!.compare(dateFormatter.date(from: rhs.date)!) == .orderedAscending
    })
}
```

However, I would change the `Task` type to hold a Date instead of a String...

```
struct Task: Codable {
    let date: Date
}
```

Then this would work:

```
tasks.map { tasks in
    tasks.sorted(by: { $0.date.compare($1.date) == .orderedAscending })
}
```

Comment: you helped me find a solution, by inserting inside my object a method that gives back the date I need, could you help me with this too? same problem, different issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68194956/in-rxswift-how-to-avoid-this-section-division